# Solving for range of c values in Fixed Point Iteration

Tags: calculus, computer-science, fixed-point-theorems

For $x^3−2x^2−13x+30 = 0$, with root r = 3. I am supposed to add $cx$ to both sides of the equation before dividing by $c$ to obtain the fixed point equation $$g(x)=x$$ where $$g(x) = \frac{1}{c}x^3−\frac{2}{c}x^2−\frac{13-c}{c}x+\frac{30}{c}$$ I was then told to find the values of c such that the fixed point iteration locally convergent to r = 3.

My idea is to differentiate g(x) to get $g'(x) = \frac{3}{c}x^2-\frac{4}{c}x+\frac{c-13}{c}$. For fixed point iteration to locally converge, $|g'(x)| < 1$. However, when trying to solve $|g'(x)| < 1$, I realise there are both $x$ and $c$ present. Am I supposed to use $b^2 - 4ac > 0$ to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes to your last question.

Comment: But if I used $b^2-4ac=0$, why would it still locally converge to r = 3? I looked at the graph and there are technically 3 intercepts for y = g(x) and y = x. Sorry but I am kinda lost :(

Comment: See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=max++%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7Bc%7Dx%5E2-%5Cfrac%7B4%7D%7Bc%7Dx%2B%5Cfrac%7Bc-13%7D%7Bc%7D

Comment: Why is maximising g'(x) necessary? I thought we are trying to find $c$ that can allow fixed point iteration locally convergent to r = 3, which should occur somewhere close to when g'(x) = 0?